# f:param works only first time when using the same name in multiple commandButtons

Tags: jsf-2, primefaces, download, parameter-passing

My requierement is to upload some data and generate different reports for download with one click. In the example below I show appropriate button witch has a parameter that is sent to the download bean to select the correct version of the report.

But the `f:param` is only set the first time a `p:commandButton` is executed and then stays the same also for other buttons. Why is that and how can I solve this issue?

```
<h:form id="mainForm" enctype="multipart/form-data">
   <p:fileUpload ...../>
   ....
   ....
   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="opt1"
      <p:ajax event="change" update="hiddingPanel"/>
   </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

   <p:selectBooleanCheckbox id="opt2"
      <p:ajax event="change" update="hiddingPanel"/>
   </p:selectBooleanCheckbox>

   <h:panelGroup id="hiddingPanel">
      <p:commandButton id="doOpt1" rendered="#{bean.opt1 and !bean.opt2}"
         actionListener="#{bean.readFile}" ajax="false" />

         <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadBean.content}" />
         <f:param name="reportType" value="REPORT1"/>

      </p:commandButton>

      <p:commandButton id="doOpt1" rendered="#{!bean.opt1 and bean.opt2}"
         actionListener="#{bean.readFile}" ajax="false" />

         <p:fileDownload value="#{downloadBean.content}" />
         <f:param name="reportType" value="REPORT2"/>

      </p:commandButton>
   </h:panelGroup>
</h:form>
```

Thanks for any suggestions!

Regards.

Comment: What logic distinguishes a `hiddingPanel` ajax-update made by `opt1` or `opt2`? A rule of thumb is to leave a fileupload component in it's own separate `h:form` - it doesn't play well with other form components unfortunately

Comment: @kolosus Not sure I understand your question. The `hiddenpanel` is not the issue here, I've tried without it also, even if both command buttons are rendered from the start, the behavior remains the same. It's like the execution of one command button sets the ` f:param` for all and only the first time,